# Why is the linux ELF loader called sometimes interpreter?

Tags: linux

I have always been wondering, why is Linux ELF "loader" called interpreter? I mean, in standard programming meaning, an interpreter is used to run scripts, but ELF has machine code instructions. So it's more like the Windows loader.

I am really confused here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interpreter is a program that translates code into immediate action, as opposed to a compiler, which translates one kind of code into another. An ELF interpreter translates the linking instructions embedded in the executable into the actions of loading the necessary dynamic libraries.